# WCF on Azure App Service - Error You do not have permission to view this directory or page

Tags: azure, wcf, azure-web-app-service

I am facing issues with WCF - on Azure App Service.

I am getting below error

"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I can see Web.config using the Console in the App Service. I have tried application log but don't see any error there

I have checked everything but still same issue

Update:

I get below error

```
This is the generic Access Denied error returned by IIS. Typically, there is a substatus code associated with this error that describes why the server denied the request. Check the IIS Log file to determine whether a substatus code is associated with this failure.
```

Comment: You offer a bit less content. First of all, based on your mistake, it should be a problem on IIS. It is recommended that you check the **authentication and authorization settings**, **URL authorization rules**, **IP address and domain restrictions** and **request filtering rules** on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

**WCF** will not directly load in the Azure Web app you need to append the **`service.svc file  in the web app url`** and test this url in **`WcfTestClient.exe`** like below:-

I have deployed one default WCF project and one WCF project from this [**Github repository**](https://github.com/kathleenwest/MyAzureWCFServiceDemo), I published this Projects to Azure Web app with **`.NET Runtime`** and the Web URL with service.svc appended loaded successfully like below:-

***Make sure to disable HTTPS only option from your Web app:-***

***Github Repository Project output:-***

[image]

**URL:-**

```http
http://siliconwebappwcf.azurewebsites.net/PositiveAffirmationService.svc
```

[image]

**WCF Test Client:-**

[image]

***Default WCF project output:-***

[image]

**URL:-**

```http
http://valleywcfchat.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc
```

[image]

**WCF Test client:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sidd, I have checked all the settings are fine as I compared them with your screenshots.  Same error TTP Error 401.83 - Unauthorized. You do not have permission to view this directory or page.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul>  <li>The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request

Comment: Try to enable the Basic Authentication and FTP authentication in your Azure Web App> configuration settings like this - https://i.imgur.com/GHnvwKH.png

Comment: its already enabled

Comment: How did you deploy your Web app? By which method?

Comment: This was done using publish from VS I believe. We have PROD Environment as well, which is working fine. I compared the two settings as well

Comment: What will be the solution for this 401.83: Authentication failed because the specified authentication token was invalid. I know I have a valid secret

Comment: Is there any authentication method in your WCF app code? For example- Client secret credentials? service principal or OAuth authentication? also, Even I faced this error, But after enabling Basic and FTP authentication to Yes, this error resolved

Comment: We don't have any auth code in the WCF. The same Service is running fine on PROD.

Comment: If the PROD is running normally, can we check the configuration information about authentication on your Azure?

Comment: @Akshay If you can share your Github repository, I can surely try